# How to get the result in every round in a for loop in R

Tags: r

I want to have the indices for every "1" on a row of a matrix. However, when I coded as the followings, only the result for the last row outputs. How can I fix the problem and what is wrong with my code?

```
adjacency <- function(x) {
  num_row <- nrow(x)
  for (i in num_row){
    output <- which (x[i,]==1)
    print(output)
  }
  result <- list (output)
  print(result)
}

A <- matrix(c(NA,1,0,1,1,NA,1,0,0,1,NA,1,1,0,1,NA),nrow=4)
A
adjacency(A)
```

Comment: You can let go off the `for` loop by using `which(A == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)` which gives you row and column index for 1's in `A`.

Answer (score 0):

You were only iterating over a single value, the number of rows in your matrix, and not over each row:

```
adjacency <- function(x) {
  num_row <- nrow(x)
  result<-list()
  for (i in 1:num_row){
    result[[i]] <- which (x[i,]==1)
  }
  print(result)
}

A <- matrix(c(NA,1,0,1,1,NA,1,0,0,1,NA,1,1,0,1,NA),nrow=4)
A
adjacency(A)
[[1]]
[1] 2 4

[[2]]
[1] 1 3

[[3]]
[1] 2 4

[[4]]
[1] 1 3
```

Comment: Thx!!! By the way, what if I do not need a list as the output? If I use result[i] instead of result[[I]], it returns an error. Why?

Comment: I think it's because result[i] expect only one value while the which function can return several. If you want to store the results in a vector I would use vector concatenation: result = c(result, which(...)). But don't forget to initialise your result vector before the loop with result = c()